# Android Cardinal Mobile SDK Issue

Tags: mobile, xamarin.android, sdk, nuget-package

Recently review my app, and found that app is not compliant with one or more of our Developer Program Policies. Please resolve this issue within 60 days of the issuance of this notification or your new releases may be rejected or the app may be removed from Google Play. See below for more information about your app’s status and how to correct the issue.
[image]

i have to check in my, and i can not see the **Cardinal Mobile SDK** related plugin or SDK in my app.

Comment: You might be using some plugin or a binding library which may have a dependency on Cardinal Mobile SDK

Comment: I've received the same email have you found the solution? @sumit

Answer (score 0):

in my case, braintree plugin uses this library.

to detect from where this library came from - you can print your dependencies tree:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

and search for cardinal source.

if the list is too long for terminal output - use this

```
./gradlew app:dependencies | grep cardinal
```

if your issue is with braintree SDK for PayPal integration, add this to the bottom of your dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
  // Your dependency declarations...
  components.all {
    allVariants {
      withDependencies { deps ->
        deps.each { dep ->
          if (dep.group == 'net.minidev' && dep.name =='json-smart') {
              dep.version {
                prefer "2.3"
              }
              dep.because "resolving dependencies issue"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I changed this line with the recommended google play version for this lib:

prefer "2.3" -> prefer "2.2.7-2"

[source](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/client-side/android/v3)

Comment: I am using paypal and i am also facing this issue, can you explain what actually this issue means?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding new library in android/build.gradle.
**You have to see the right version on external libraries.**

```
dependencies {
    //Cardinal Mobile SDK
    implementation 'org.jfrog.cardinalcommerce.gradle:cardinalmobilesdk:2.2.7-2'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:5.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```